# Auto Formatting to Specific Type of Document in Microsoft Teams Chat Text Box

Tags: c#, formatting, chatbot, microsoft-teams, autoformatting

I have some share point  URLs of documents mostly .DOCX.and .PDF.  I had developed teams bot and deployed.  So when I am copy pasting of any of my share point document URL in teams bot chat text box, immediately it is formatted to specific type of file automatically and showing document file name along with extension in chat text box control and same showing as response once click enter button. But the same share point URL if I am sending as message from my bot  it’s not formatted in bot response.

**Before Enter : Teams Bot chat text box control:**

[image]

**After Sending/Click Enter in Teams:**

[image]

**Sending same Share point URL as message from Bot:**

```
          var reply1 = MessageFactory.Text($"<SHAREPOINTURL>");
          reply1.TextFormat = "xml";   --Any specific format we need to use here to display as like above screenshot
          await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply1, cancellationToken);
          //Output: Normal text message

         var reply2 = MessageFactory.Text($"[SHAREPOINTLINK](sharepointURL)");
         await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply2, cancellationToken);
          //Output: SHAREPOINTLINK (which is hyperlinked with URL i mentioned.
```

***How to achieve the output like as shown in pic(Formatted as Document)***

Comment: Please take a look at [Send and receive files with a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet) documentation. You can use [FileCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-and-receive-files?tabs=dotnet#example-using-the-bot-framework-sdk) for this.

Comment: File Card is just to accept or decline file . But my question is how exactly auto formatting is happening in Teams.

Comment: Auto formatting of a file by just pasting the link to the file is not possible while using Bots. Please check this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/6ba153cab7426e4061e3283037ef0091d481a43e/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload/Bots/TeamsFileUploadBot.cs#L61) to see how File card can be used to send files.